# Group by and Join on same table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table which contains following records.

```
         acct_id | org_id | terr_id | segment 4       
         --------------------------------------
         123     | A      | 12345   | US
         123     | A      | 45678   | CA
         456     | B      | ABC     | US
         456     | B      | XYZ     | US
```

I need to group by on acct_id and org_id and get the record with max(segment 4).. While grouping by I need to omit terr_id in group by and I need it in the output for the associated max(segment 4). How can I do it without joining back to the same table again?

o/p needs to be

```
         acct_id | org_id | terr_id | segment 4       
         --------------------------------------
         123     | A      | 12345   | US
         456     | B      | ABC or XYZ  | US
```

Comment: Hi, please edit the question and add what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inner join with grouped  by for max(segment_4)

```
  select acct_id , org_id , terr_id , segment_4
  from my_table m
  inner join (

      select acct_id, org_id, max(segment_4 ) as my_segment_4
      from my_table 
      group by acct_id, org_id 
  )  t o t.acct_id  = m.acct_id 
              and t.org_id = m.org_id 
                  and t.my_segment_4 = m.segment_4
```

Comment: Hi ScaisEdge - is there a way I can do this without joining back to the same table?

Comment: for what i know  ,, not .. because you need  the terr_id related  to the max(segment_4) and for this you need  a separated  access to my_table  .. you could use a single access  if you instead of the terr_id related  to the max(segment_4)you want an aggrenated  result over  terr_id eg: min

Comment: Hi ScaisEdge - Is there a way I can get only one record if multiple Terr_ID's were existing for combination of acct_id, org_id and segment 4?

Comment: I can not understand your question  .. so post a new question with a valid  data sample and the expetced  result and comment me the link of the new post  .. so i can try to answer

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT Distinct acct_ID
        , Org_ID
        , Terr_ID
        , Segment4
        , row_number() over (partition by ACCT_ID, Org_ID order by terr_ID asc) RN
   FROM Table
   WHERE Terr_ID <> '45678')
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE RN = 1
```